# How to display a report in a slideshow extender?

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio-2010, report, slideshow

I have a report and I would like to display the report with hyperlinks in a slideshow extender? How do I achieve this? Please guide me thanks

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-SlideShow-Extender-control-Tutorial-with-Example.aspx

Comment: yes I have read that article but I have tried converting the report to an image and showing it in a slideshow extender but what I need here is a completely different requirement. I need to portray the report with hyperlink on one particular column and when I hover my mouse over it I should be able to click it and go to a next page, I can't show the hyperlink for a particular column in an image right for a slideshow extender. @Musthaan

Comment: i think better to use http://bxslider.com/ instead of extender. you can do without converting to image.

Comment: Ok thanks @Musthaan I'll try using that